# Edit SSRS report without using BIDS

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am using BIDS (Business Intelligence Developpement Studio) to create reports after that i publish it to integrate them in asp.net application.

I want to edit report in my application without using BIDS like this
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please use Report Builder for edit the report

Open report server url on internet explorer

http://reportserverIPaddress.com/Reports

Login in report server by entering the userid and password.

[image]

Edit the report in report builder as below

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help , but i have beeb installed Report Builder and i cant found it in the top menu (i open it just like BIDS)
![enter image description here][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/zVoCv.png

Comment: I think you have no permission to edit the report in report builder. You have to go into site setting=>security and check the permission

Comment: I want another solution using the web ;any solution ?

Comment: Report builder is more efficient for ssrs report design as above I have show it in my answer you can locally download the report builder 3.0 and design the report. for more information please read below link http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159253(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: so there no issue to modify report via web ?

Comment: Yeah,If you have permission to edit the report in report builder as above picture. First time it will some time to install the report builder on your machine next time when you click in edit the report in report builder it will open the report in report builder. See my updated answer